# Convert date strings with R

Tags: r, date, format

I’m working with `date strings` in `R`. Essentially, I have three different `strings` that represent date variables. I have these weird date `strings` from `scraping data` on the `web`.

Is it possible to convert these three different date `strings` into a universal format that makes it easier to perform logic on them with basic `R` code? Here are what the `strings` look like. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
1. "Wed, Feb 7, 2017  7:30 pm"
2. "Wed Feb  7 08:00:04 2017"
3. "2017-02-7 13:06:14 PST"  # Sys.time()
```

UPDATE: I now have a better understanding of as.POSIXct now, but I still don't understand why this doesn't work ?

```
as.POSIXct('02/15/2017, 10:00 PM', format = "%M/%D/%Y, %H:%M %r")
```

Comment: For 1: `as.POSIXct("Wed, Feb 7, 2017 7:30 pm", format = "%A, %b %d,%Y %H:%M")`

Comment: For 2: `as.POSIXct("Wed Feb 7 08:00:04 2017", format = "%A %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")`

Comment: @d.b, exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @d.b why doesn't this work? as.POSIXct('02/15/2017, 10:08:26 pm', format = "%Y/%M/%S, %H:%M:%S %r") ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your specific question has already been answered in comments.

I would like to leave this as a general reference for other people who might have similar problems and can come across this question.

So, as you have this in d.b's comment, your data time string have been parsed via command:

```
as.POSIXct("Wed, Feb 7, 2017 7:30 pm", format = "%A, %b %d,%Y %H:%M")
```

The difference between your first and the second case was in the `format`.

So, this is a general guidance on the format:

- **`%a`** Abbreviated weekday
- **`%A`** Full weekday
- **`%b`** Abbreviated month
- **`%B`** Full month
- **`%c`** Locale-specific date and time
- **`%d`** Decimal date
- **`%H`** Decimal hours (24 hour)
- **`%I`** Decimal hours (12 hour)
- **`%j`** Decimal day of the year
- **`%m`** Decimal month
- **`%M`** Decimal minute
- **`%p`** Locale-specific AM/PM
- **`%S`** Decimal second
- **`%U`** Decimal week of the year (starting on Sunday)
- **`%w`** Decimal Weekday (0=Sunday)
- **`%W`** Decimal week of the year (starting on Monday)
- **`%x`** Locale-specific Date
- **`%X`** Locale-specific Time
- **`%y`** 2-digit year
- **`%Y`** 4-digit year
- **`%z`** Offset from GMT
- **`%Z`** Time zone (character)

This is also useful if you want to do the conversions between different formats:

```
x <- as.POSIXct( "2017-01-15")
format(x, "%a")
[1] "Sun"
format(x, "Week of the year: %W")
[1] "Week of the year: 02"
```

source: https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html

Answer (score 0):

1. `as.POSIXct("Wed, Feb 7, 2017 7:30 pm", format = "%A, %b %d,%Y %H:%M", tz="PST8PDT")`
2. `as.POSIXct("Wed Feb 7 08:00:04 2017", format = "%A %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y",tz="PST8PDT")`
3. `as.POSIXct("2017-02-7 13:06:14 PST", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="PST8PDT")`